# Why PyDev cannot find math for import

Tags: python, autocomplete, pydev

In PyDev when I do CTRL-SPACE after 'import' command I cannot get it to auto-complete for math. I know math is a built in C library, but it would be nice if PyDev knew about all modules available for import not just the .py files in the Libs folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange... for me it's appearing (as it should).

I.e.:

import mat|<-- code completion here shows 'math'.

Can you report that in the PyDev issue tracker?  (https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/)

Also, please check if you have something in your error log (http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F) and add it to the report...